# why second argument to cons must be a list

Tags: scheme, the-little-schemer

I'm reading the book called **the little schemer**.

Before read that, i've finished reading first three chapter of **SICP**.

My question is that **why second argument to cons must be a list**.

However, `(cons a b)` works for all values a and b and

`(car (cons a b))` = a

`(cdr (cons a b))` = b

Comment: It's just a Scheme/Lisp convention that a list is either nil, or a `cons` whose `cdr` is again a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument to `cons` is not *necessarily* a list. It's a list *only* if you're, well, building a list (proper or otherwise). It's perfectly valid if the `cdr` part of a `cons` cell is not a list, for example, when building an association list:

```
(define lookup-table (list (cons 'x 10) (cons 'y 20) (cons 'z 30)))
(assoc 'z lookup-table)
=> '(z . 30)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not all implementations of Lisp allow a non-list as the second argument to cons. For example, see https://scheme.cs61a.org/